# Parallax on JS & TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

```
<main class="bg-gradient-to-r from-black via-cyan to-black">
        <!--BACKDROP-->
        <section id="Home" class="h-screen">
            <h1 class=" hidden md:flex justify-center items-center z-20 absolute top-24 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 font-extrabold text-6xl text-center">John Doe</h1>
            <h2 style="top: 170px" class="z-20 absolute left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 font-light text-2xl md:text-5xl text-center ">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <img class="absolute h-full w-full object-cover top-0 left-0 z-0" src="images/backdrop1.png" alt="bg">
            <img class="absolute h-full w-full object-cover top-0 left-0 z-10" src="images/sky1.png" alt="fg">
        </section>
```

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const navigation = document.querySelector("#navigation");
    //   let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
    //   let Name = document.getElementById('Name');
    //   let mainHeader = document.getElementById('main-header');
    //   let HomeSection = document.querySelector('.Home');
  
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
  
      if (value > 0) {
        navigation.style.backgroundColor = "#000000e9";
      } else {
        navigation.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      }
  
      if (value <= HomeSection.offsetHeight) {
        Name.style.marginTop = value * 2.5 + "px";
      }
  
      if (value > HomeSection.offsetHeight) {
        logo.style.fontSize = "1.5em";
      } else {
        logo.style.fontSize = "1em";
      }
    });
  });
  
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
```

I am trying to use the parallax effect only on h1 and h2 class while scrolling, keeping these  two classes above the sky1.png image and behind the backdrop1.png.